# EaseUS taking months to recover data from external HDD, NTFS table corrupted

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery

My 1 TB external hard disc (WD - My Passport) stopped working and the NTFS table is corrupted so the drive is unreadable. I haven't formatted the drive so it shows up as RAW. I installed two programs to try to recover the data, iCare Professional and EaseUS Recovery.

Both tell me that  the estimated time needed is between 1-4 months. I've left the computer running EaseUS for two days now. Progress dialog shows that it is indeed finding files.

But I can't wait either one month (much less four) for it to finish. Is there any way to make this faster?

If I format the drive in NTFS and run the recovery programs then will it be faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data recovery on large volume drives can be such an agony especially if you are using window's tools to recover the same drive that windows is unable to read. I have had success recovering similar raw and unrecognized drives using linux distros as well. My suggestion: Download Ultimate Boot CD, make a bootable USB or CD of it. Boot from it and launch Parted Magic. Mount all partitions on the drive and see if you are able to access your lost files&copy them to another drive. If this fails, proceed with Testdisk as MOatz suggested in his comment. Testdisk&many other drive recovery tools are included in UBCD. It's your best bet. Best of Luck

Comment: I used TestDisk. Quick Search found one partition. Listing files failed because of file system error. I went for a deeper search and it's very slow. 130.000 cylinders and after 10 hours it's scanning cylinder 154. It keeps showing errors : Read error at cylinder X (lba=yyyyyy). I don't know what this means for the whole process. Should I let it keep scanning or is there no point ?

Answer (score 1):

Data recovery takes a long time, especially if we're talking about a lot of data, and extra-especially if the drive is faulty/damaged. :)

All recovery programs will take about the same amount of time to do the same job.

Formatting the drive will only make it harder to recover data (since every time you write to the drive you most-likely overwrite some of the data you are trying to recover).

Alternative technique (for next time)?  Make regular backups.

Answer (score 0):

Data recovery can take a while, although I've never seen a hard drive have to take that long to be read from and repair. What kind of state is the drive in, is it making noises, does it report bad sectors, what happened to it to make the NTFS table corrupt?

I'd start by using a tool such as [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) (packaged in linux as gddrescue) and imaging the drive to another hard drive of equal or preferably larger size. Then once imaged you can use tools such as [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or [Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover the data (or even restore the file structure to the disk if your aim is to re-use the drive).

Alternatively you could employ the services of a data recovery firm. I own one, but will resist the urge to shamelessly plug :-)

Comment: It's making some low volume ticking noises...but not something that would make you think it's broken. The error happened while I was using it. Windows popped an I/O error and suddenly the file browser opened in the drive went empty. I unplugged it and plugged it back in and it showed up in MyComputer but as RAW. For the first hour or two, even right clicking on it caused explorer to hang. Now it doesn't do that any more.I'm a bit far to employ you !

Comment: So it sounds to me like its sat there in a fixed position and the operating system is querying the drive hence the ticks every now and again. Could be a head crash, but I'd be inclined to run testdisk on it and see how that performs. I use testdisk (and all my other tools) in a linux environment but you can download it for windows too if you're more comfortable.

Comment: Whatever the weather if you can get a linux distro up and running I'd be inclined to image the drive using ddrescue then recover the data from the image

Answer (score 0):

If you format the drive data recovery won't be faster. 
If you are sure that the original problem is with a corrupted NTFS table you could try using some kind of partition recovery software. However the best option is such cases it to use the services of a data recovery company. Data recovery is not an easy process and if you aren't a 100% sure what and why you are doing you might end up losing your data.